# Is Bool -> Maybe () isomorphic?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to figure out, if `Bool -> Maybe ()` is isomorphic or not.

The possible combination are:

```
True -> Just ()
True -> Nothing
False -> Just ()
False -> Nothing
```

I would say, it is isomorphic and for every combination, it exists seperate functions to inverse it.

How to prove that the above morphism is isomorphic?

Comment: Any two types having same cardinality will always be isomorphic to one another. There will be n! unique isomorphism between them where n is cardinality. |Bool| = 2 and |Maybe ()| = 2.

Comment: "Isomorphic" is not a property of a type, it is a relation between types. So "Is `Bool -> Maybe ()` isomorphic?" is an ill-formed question, but "Are `Bool` and `Maybe ()` isomorphic?" would be sensible, as would "Are `Bool -> Maybe ()` and `(Bool, Maybe ())` isomorphic?".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Bool` and `Maybe ()` are isomorphic types ([ignoring problems involving bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54655998/1126841)), as witnessed by the following mappings between the two:

```
b2m :: Bool -> Maybe ()
b2m True = Just ()
b2m False = Nothing

m2b :: Maybe () -> Bool
m2b (Just ()) = True
m2b Nothing = False
```

It is easy to verify that `b2m . m2b` and `m2b . b2m` are both equivalent to `id`:

```
m2b . b2m $ True == m2b (b2m True) == m2b (Just ()) == True == id True
m2b . b2m $ Fals == m2b (b2m False) ==  m2b Nothing == False == id False

b2m . m2b (Just ()) == b2m (m2b (Just ())) == b2m True == Just () == id (Just ())
b2m . m2b Nothing == b2m (m2b Nothing) == b2m False == Nothing == id Nothing
```

---

In your question, you don't have a single morphism. You have the building blocks for the 4 different functions that have type `Bool -> Maybe ()`, as follows:

```
f1,f2,f3,f4 :: Bool -> Maybe ()
f1 True = Just ()
f1 False = Nothing

f2 True = Nothing
f2 False = Just ()

f3 True = Just ()
f3 False = Just ()

f4 True = Nothing
f4 False = Nothing
```

Likewise, there are 4 different functions of type `Maybe () -> Bool`:

```
f5,f6,f7,f8 :: Maybe () -> Bool
f5 (Just ()) = True
f5 Nothing = False

f6 (Just ()) = False
f6 Nothing = True

f7 (Just ()) = True
f7 Nothing = True

f8 (Just ()) = False
f8 Nothing = False
```

Some pairs of functions form an isomorphism, but some don't. The top of this answer shows that `f1` and `f5` do, but `f3` and `f8`, for example, do not.

```
f3 . f8 $ (Just ()) == f3 (f8 Just ()) == f3 False == Just () == id (Just ())
f3 . f8 $ Nothing == f3 (f8 Nothing) == f3 False == Just () != id Nothing
```

Answer (score 6):

The types are "morally" isomorphic, but not precisely isomorphic in Haskell.

`Bool` has three values: `True`, `False`, and `_|_` (bottom, representing non-termination or error).

`Maybe ()` has *four* values: `Nothing`, `Just ()`, `Just _|_`, and `_|_`.

We tend to partially order the values of a type by definedness. Under this partial order they form a *Scott domain*, which is a *meet semilattice* with certain completeness properties. In this case,

```
_|_ < Just _|_ < Just ()
_|_ < Nothing
```

Recursive types lead to more interesting domains. For example, the type `[Natural]` includes the chain

```
  _|_
< 1 : _|_
< 1 : 1 : _|_
< 1 : 1 : 2 : _|_
< ...
< fibs
```

Answer (score 4):

If we use `|T|` to donate the amount of possible values for a type, we can see that `|()| = 1` (there is only one way to construct `()`). Furthermore, we can see that for `data Maybe a = Just a | Nothing` we have `|Maybe a| = 1 + |a|`, and thus `|Maybe ()| = 1 + |()| = 1 + 1 = 2`. Therefore, there are two distinct values for `|Maybe ()|`. The same exercise for `data Bool = True | False` shows us that `|Bool| = 1 + 1 = 2`, and so both of these types have exactly the same number of inhabitants.

To show these types are isomorphic we just need to construct an isomorphism. That's a function from one type to the other, such that there is also an inverse function:

```
toBool :: Maybe () -> Bool
toBool Nothing = False
toBool (Just ()) = True

fromBool :: Bool -> Maybe ()
fromBool False = Nothing
fromBool True = Just ()
```

Such that `toBool . fromBool = id` and `fromBool . toBool = id`.